# Error: : Failure: Tx Failed: Keyset failure (keys-all): 'todo-admin-keyset' while deploying on Kadena Testnet

Tags: blockchain, pact-lang, kadena

The yaml deployment file is as under:
codeFile: pact/todos.pact
networkId: testnet04
publicMeta:
chainId: "1"
gasLimit: 1000
ttl: 28000
creationTime:
sender: "nambi001"
gasPrice: 0.00001
data:
todo-admin-keyset: ["ba54b224d1924dd98403f5c751abdd10de6cd81b0121800bf7bdbdcfaec7388d"]
keyPairs:
public: ba54b224d1924dd98403f5c751abdd10de6cd81b0121800bf7bdbdcfaec7388d
secret: 8693e641ae2bbe9ea802c736f42027b03f86afe63cae315e7169c9c496c17332
nonce: fetch-todos
The request key for detailed transaction log is : tnx2phZpQOyOtloY2eD4M48yzm_tOpqeq9abNn2TGCo

Comment: Use more markup to improve the readability of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error for your request key on the explorer:    `{ type : TxFailure , message : Keyset failure (keys-all): 'todo-admin-keyset , info : <interactive>:0:58 , callStack : [<interactive>:0:58: (define-keyset "todo-admin-keyset" (native read-keyset Read KEY from message data ...)] }`

Use

```
(describe-keyset 'todo-admin-keyset)
```

To view the keyset and you will see it doesn't match your keyset. That is because someone else registered the name todo-admin-keyset.
You need to use a different, unique name for your keyset.

Comment: making it todoxxx-admin-keyset helped! thanks